# When Retrieving data from the database, I have got a null value, How to fix this?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-5

*Firstly*, I am using ASP.net MVC 5 Framework. I was tried to access Bid Model class and retrieve my username in the database. But it is not work.

*Here is my Auction Controller* - **(I commented the area that need to change )**

```
            var result = auction.Bids.Where(c => c.AuctionId.ToString() == bid.AuctionId.ToString()&&c.Amount> bid.Amount);
            //I want to get my username in bids model, but it is not retrieving........................................
            if (result.Equals(null))
                {

                    TempData["Hello"] = "Sorry the bid has been expired!";
                        return RedirectToAction("Auction", new { id = bid.AuctionId });
                }
                else
                {
                    TempData["Hello"] = "Bid has a won person";

                    return RedirectToAction("Auction", new { id = bid.AuctionId });
                }
                //TempData["Hello"] = "This bid has expired!";


        }
        else
        {
            var result = db.Bids.Where(c => c.AuctionId.Equals(bid.AuctionId));
            if (result.Equals(" "))
            {
                TempData["Hello"] = "Sorry the bid has been expired!";
                return RedirectToAction("Auction", new { id = bid.AuctionId });
            }
            else
            {
                TempData["Hello"] = "Bid has a won person";
                return RedirectToAction("Auction", new { id = bid.AuctionId });
            }
           //TempData["Hello"] = "This bid has expired!";

        }
```

***Here is my Auction model***

```
using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace Samurai.Models
    {
        public class Auction
        {
            [Key]
            [Required]
            public long Id { get; set; }


            public virtual Collection<Bid> Bids { get; private set; }

            public int BidCount
            {
                get { return Bids.Count; }
            }
            public Auction()
            {
                Bids = new Collection<Bid>();
                CurrentPrice = 0;

            }
        }
    }
```

***Here is my Bid Model***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Samurai.Models
{
    public class Bid
    {
        [Key]
        [Required]
        public long Id { get; internal set; }

        [Required]
        public long AuctionId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Username { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Range(1, double.MaxValue)]
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }

        public Bid()
        {
            Timestamp = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me to solve this.. I am tried so much, but still I can't figured it out..this is 4th day that I am trying.. please help me...

This is the place in ActionResult bids section appears null value

```
 var result = auction.Bids.Where(c => c.AuctionId.ToString() == bid.AuctionId.ToString()&&c.Amount> bid.Amount);
```

this is need to change, but I don't know how to change this, I tried different ways..but it is not working...

**What I am trying to do is:**

(Simply I am trying to do here, in bid model - I was defined a username section. So, I want to retrieve the value which is reference to the bid id)

**But I tried several times to get the username in the bid model, but "result" variable always null...**

I was tried to pass the auction id and retrieve the list, but it is the same...:(

**I attached some pictures that I hope it will give some information to you..
Please help me**

Checking details pointing to the object - "i.stack.imgur.com/Ecd25.png"

[Auction database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8OMv.png)

[Bid Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3hz2.png)

***Thanks....***

Comment: did you check that the AuctionId is passed in the model?                                1- why not use Html.HiddenFor (put in partial View if the model of the view is different to avoid typos, plus its better organized) @Html.Hidden("auctionId", auction.Id) 2- check the values of the where conditions , are they correct ?

Comment: @SaadAlothman - yes they are correct

Comment: AuctionId is also working, perfectly, only problem var result section in the controller

Comment: If you get a null reference exception on that line then it seems to me that auction.Bids is null. Can you verify this?

Comment: @RuardvanElburg - have a look I updated the links, in the end -  you will see " Auction database" and "Bid database".. Click and see...My database values are there

Comment: @RuardvanElburg - I checked the database, so no null values are there, still can't figure it out :( ..

Comment: I am talking about the code not the database. Split the line var result = auction.Bids.Where(c => c.AuctionId.ToString() == bid.AuctionId.ToString()&&c.Amount> bid.Amount); into two lines:
var q = auction.Bids; var result = q.Where(c => c.AuctionId.ToString() == bid.AuctionId.ToString()&&c.Amount> bid.Amount);
Is auction.Bids == null?

Comment: Please refer [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - the key word being **minimal**

Comment: @RuardvanElburg - I will try and let you know

Comment: @StephenMuecke - Sorry about that , apologies, I will later on do that also :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this line you was use auction.Bids like EntityFramework collections. But i see you didnt design your Models with 1 to Many Relations.
for this reason your Bids must be null when you trying to call.

My advice 1: you must cahnge your model for 1 to many relations for automatic Collections lazy load with EntityFramework.

2: or you have to update your code like this :

```
db.Bids.Where(c => c.AuctionId == bid.AuctionId && c.Amount> bid.Amount);
```

so, query from directly to db context. not on auction collection. Because it will null in this design. (till you load)

Comment: I updated some attached pictures , have a look :) thanks for suggestions , I appreciated :)

Comment: thank you for the suggestions, I really appreciated it :)

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to debug the method and see if the problem is data related. That way you can know if the lookup is failing because of the amount and/or the string conversion.

So first try using changing the line to this one:

```cs
var result = auction.Bids.Where(c => c.AuctionId == bid.AuctionId);
```

If it works then add the Amount filter:

```cs
var result = auction.Bids.Where(c => c.AuctionId == bid.AuctionId && c.Amount > bid.Amount);
```

My gut tells me it's because of the *Amount*, as the string conversion although unnecessary should still work.

***EDIT:***

After some reading the problem may be that your virtual collection is not being eagerly loaded, try using include, which forces the query to look for the nested entity.

Try this one:

```cs
var auction = db.Auctions.Include(a => a.Bids).SingleOrDefault(a => a.Id  == bid.AuctionId);
```

For more information about include you can read more in [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I was tried both ways , but it is says null ( still cannot figure :(

Comment: I updated some attached pictures , have a look :) thanks for suggestions , I appreciated :)

Comment: @SumedhaWarakagoda See the edit and check if that's the issue.